# Importance of clearing cookies in Selenium RC/WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

My team-lead told me that (while executing **data driven testing** using for loop with a excel file) the usage clearing cookies is a smart method. I didn't exactly understand why is it necessary to clear cookies while doing this.

Comment: did you ask your teamlead for an explanation?

Comment: No he just told me that is the smart way but didn't ask for explanation at that moment , after thinking about this wants to know the reason

Comment: In general, you will clear cookies in between tests if you think that cookies set by one test will interfere with the next test.

Comment: I would have thought it's literally just ensuring you start from a clean slate.

Comment: I use SauceLabs and so its always a new browser on every test and so the cache is brand new, regardless.